# postgresql cumsum by condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table

[image]

I need to calculate cumsum group by `id` for every row with `type="end"`.
Can anyone see the problem?

Output result

[image]

Comment: In order for your question to make sense, you need an ordering column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, i've just added the 'created' column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  One method is to assign a grouping by *reverse* counting the ends.  Then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by grp desc) as result
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where type = 'end') over (order by created desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can also do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (count(*) filter (where type = 'end') over () -
        count(*) filter (where type = 'end') over (order by created desc) -
        1
       )
from t;
```

Comment: @formanite . . . It is a column alias on an expression in the subquery.

Comment: Why do you use dense_rank? If I delete row with dense_rank i get the same result

Comment: select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where type = 'end') over (order by created desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t